# Twitter feed not showing the tweets

Tags: javascript, twitter

In my website the twitter feed is not showing the tweets.But it works well on localhost.The problem occurs when it uploaded to the server. Could anyone please help me?
Here is the code

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" width="230" height="300" href="https://twitter.com/myusername" data-widget-id="MY WIDGET ID" >Tweets by @username</a>

 <script>
!function(d,s,id)
{
var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(!d.getElementById(id))
{
js=d.createElement(s);j
s.id=id;
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
}
}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Also I have used another code ,it works on server but not showing the picture from the tweets.Its shows the link for the particular picture.Here is the code.

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>

<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
         version: 2,
         type: 'profile',
         rpp: 4,
         interval: 2000,
         width: 230, //we've changed our default width, to make it prettier
         height: 300,
         theme: {
               shell: {
                 background: 'transparent', //this is important
                 color: 'rgb(255, 103, 0);'
               },
               tweets: {
                 background: 'transparent', //this is important
                 color: '#aba2a2',
                 links: '#ccc'
               }
         },
         features: {
               scrollbar: false,
               loop: true,
               live: true,
               hashtags: true,
               timestamp: true,
               avatars: true,
               behavior: 'default'
         }

       }).render().setUser('user').start();
</script>
```

Is there any settings for showing the picture on tweets?

Answer (score 0):

Public domain need to specified on timeline configuration section
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

Comment: I have specified the domain name on timeline configuration ,but it doesn`t work